# Sending objects from one jsp to another on hitting a link

Tags: jsp

I tried to find solution for this. But I didn't find answer to my specific problem.

I have an object in a JSP. On hitting a href link want to navigate to a new JSP. Trying to access the list of jsp1 in the second JSP. But getting null pointer exception. I understand that I some how need to pull the object here.

Looking for some help here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSTL tag  .

For example :-in first jsp you can set as below

```
<body>
<%
  ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
  list.add("abcd");
  list.add("abcd");
  request.setAttribute("list",list);
%>
 <c:set var="list"  value="${list}" scope="session"/>
<a href="next.jsp">Click Here</a>
</body>
```

And in the second Jsp(next.jsp) you can get list like below:-

```
<body>
<c:out value="${list}" />

</body>
```